# The rank of the power of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> The rank of the power of a symmetric matrix.

The task is to show that $g(S) = S^3-S^2+S$ has the same rank as $S$. Here $S$ is a symmetric matrix.

I think, that the key to the solution of the problem is to show that the powers of a symmetric matrix $S$ have the same rank as $S$. I don't know how to show that. (Eigenvalue decomposition is not allowed).

Comment: Remark 1: You should emphasize this is a problem for real matrices. The statement is not true in the complex case. Remark 2: what are the zeros of $g(c)=x^3-x^2+x$? What does this imply?

Comment: @Benjamin The only real zero is $0$. I am struggling to see the implication. Do you mean that g(S) is invertible or something like that (Is that even a thing for g(S) to be invertible)?

Comment: 1 If you know the algebraic multiplicity of zero you know the rank of the matrix. 2 If $S$ is a real matrix, then by being symmetric it is Hermitian. For Hermitian matrices, there is Theorem that for (possibly complex) polynomial $p$ we can get spectrum of matrix  $p(A)$ by taking spectrum of $A$ and applying $p$ to all its elements.

Answer (score 2):

For real $S$.

$S^3-S^2+S=S(S^2-S+I)$ and so it suffices to prove that $S^2-S+I$ is invertible. Suppose, on the contrary, that $W=$ Kernel$(S^2-S+I)$ is non-empty.

$S$ is symmetric on $W$ and so has an eigenvector, $v\in W$. Let $S(v)=\lambda v$, where $\lambda $ is real. But then $(S^2-S+I)v=(\lambda^2-\lambda+1)v\ne 0$, a contradiction.